# Best way to cache large image on IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, caching

I have an image of 2900x2379.
I have created a asp.net ashx handler that will load this image and crop a smaller image from it and return that crop as a stream.

In pseudoish code I have this in my handler...:

```
Bitmap LargeBMPToUse = null;
if (Application["MyLargeImage]" == null)
{
LargeBMPToUse  = new Bitmap("File location of image on my server");
Application["MyLargeImage"] = LargeBMPToUse;
}

//now crop image from LargeBMPToUse  and return its stream
```

My question is whether there are more efficient ways of doing this and/or whether I should definitely NOT do it this way.

Additional, I cannot/will not use any Client-Caching techniques.

Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't you just resize the image to the smaller size and just keep it this way?

Comment: I am 'cropping' apart of the big image and not resizing it..

Comment: So why don't you save the cropped image?

Comment: Start by not using the `application` variables, that is static and stay on memory.

Comment: There are multiple reasons I am tied by.  The issue/question is whether this is the best way to cache an image on the server to work on in subsequent calls and not architecture choices :)

Comment: @aristos Hi, thanks for reply.  This is the point. I need it to be stored as a static object so it can be used to retrieved on by any User who asks for it and not on a session by session basis.  If I have 2 Users requesting a crop of this image it may be at different ROIs and it would be waste of memory to load this image twice.

Comment: @danrhul Hi, what do you mean by that statement?

Comment: I.e. It's not the best way.

Comment: If the Client wants to work with this large image which incidentally could be many big images and I have users requesting portions of this image and I have no say about the design that led to that situation then the question IS what i originally asked..

Comment: I totally agree with you but my hands are tied

Comment: I cannot cache on client side. I cannot split this large image permently into smaller bits..

Comment: @folks. This is why I am asking the question here as I would not do it this way by choice. It is so odd and against the grain I need to explore options in these constraints

Comment: Have you tried using HttpContext.Current.Cache?

Comment: @AndreiD Hi, no not yet, I was looking at memory mapped files.  Is this more efficent do you think?

Comment: My guess is the performance is about the same on your solution, but using Cache class you get more features like expiration time on your objects. Also I read somewhere that IIS manages the cache automatically, so if it gets too big, it deletes what it considers unnecessary

Comment: I see. Well that would offer some improvements to the manageability of it all.  I just tested the app in a multi-user environment and the response time is dire.  What did they expect and what a pain..

Comment: I would assume the bottleneck on this kind of app would be the code handling the cropping of the image, and not the way you obtain the image. Are you sure this is really your problem?

Comment: Hi, I knew that the cropping would be the issue.  I was just looking at other ways to optimise things. I think i will have to tell them that the large image has to be permanently split into smaller ones if we are to stand any chance of making this work.

Comment: Yeah, I tought that would be the best solution from the start.

Comment: The trouble with Software IT managers is that they know nothing about software. Apologies if you are a PM :)

Comment: Also:  You didn't ask for advice on your image handler (and I realize I'm going to sound like a douche), but please don't write it yourself.  Use something like this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfWeek11ImageResizerEnablesCleanClearImageResizingInASPNET.aspx .  There are literally hundreds of ways to screw up image handling.  You're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @DanEsparza I was using EMGU..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no quick and easy answer to this question**, but I will suggest you avoid putting things in 'Application' unless you really need to.

[HttpContext.Current.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache.aspx) is a better choice.  [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.ASPX) is not a cache, its a global named value collection: If you add an object to Application it will stay until a an app pool recycle.

More importantly (from the docs, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.ASPX)):

> **Application state is free-threaded**, which means that application state
>   data can be accessed simultaneously by many threads. Therefore, it is
>   important to ensure that when you update application state data, you
>   **do so in a thread-safe manner** by including built-in synchronization
>   support. You can use the Lock and UnLock methods to ensure data
>   integrity by locking the data for writing by only one source at a
>   time. You can also reduce the likelihood of concurrency problems by
>   initializing application state values in the Application_Start method
>   in the Global.asax file.

Please don't store images in the Application object.  Please.

Comment: Hi Dam, thanks for your info.  This is not something I would do by choice or had even considered as I would never normally get to this stage.  I knew it was free-threaded  and had implemented locks around this 'object'. Fortunately, I had managed to convince my PM to abandon this approach and i have now implemented splitting the large image from the off which is now accessible via URLs. Thank God!

Comment: @Folks everyone please be aware I was play 'Devils Advocate' here. I know storing images into app cache is a bad idea. I just wanted a). Alternatives (in this particular scenario as I was stuck myself) and b). Good arguments to present to my PM. I am glad everyone agreed it was a bad idea :)